# почему у меня получается что быстрая сортировка скорее слиянием

Tags: c++

```
Quick sort

#include<iostream>
    #include<time.h>
    #include<Windows.h>
    #define N 80000
    using namespace std;
    int* ar; 
    int swaps = 0, compares = 0;
    double Th()
    {
        SYSTEMTIME time;
        GetSystemTime(&time);
        double chas;
        chas = time.wHour * 60 * 60 * 1000 + time.wMinute * 60 * 1000 + time.wSecond * 1000 + time.wMilliseconds;
        return chas;
    }
    void funcprint(int arr[], int size)
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < size; i++)
            cout << arr[i] << " ";
        cout << endl;
    }
    void quickSort(int a[], int size) {
        if (size < 2) {
            return;
        }
    
        long i = 0, j = size - 1;
        int p = a[size >> 1];
    
        while (i < j) {
            while (a[i] < p) { compares++;  i++; }
            while (a[j] > p) { compares++;  j--; }
            if (i < j) {
                swaps++;
                swap(a[i++], a[j--]);
            }
        }
        quickSort(a, j);
        quickSort(a + i, size - i);
    }
    
    int main() {
        int* a = new int[N];
        ar = a; 
        srand(time(NULL));
        for (int i = 0; i <= N; i++) {
    
            a[i] = rand();
        }
        double T, t1, t0;
        t0 = Th();
        quickSort(a, N);
        t1 = Th();
        T = (t1 - t0) / 1000.0;
        cout << "Quick sort" << endl;
        cout << "Number of elements:" << N << endl;
        cout << "compares=" << compares << endl;
        cout << "swaps=" << swaps << endl;
        cout << "Time:" << T << endl;
    
    }
```

Merge sort

```
#include <iostream>
#include<time.h>
#include<Windows.h>
#define N 80000
int swaps = 0, compares = 0;
using namespace std;
double Th()
{
    SYSTEMTIME time;
    GetSystemTime(&time);
    double chas;
    chas = time.wHour * 60 * 60 * 1000 + time.wMinute * 60 * 1000 + time.wSecond * 1000 + time.wMilliseconds;
    return chas;
}
void Merge(int* A, int first, int last) {
    int middle, start, final, j;
    int* mas = new int[N];
    middle = (first + last) / 2;
    start = first;
    final = middle + 1;
    for (j = first; j < last; j++) {
        swaps++;
        if ((start <= middle) && (final <= last))
        {
            compares++;
            mas[j] = (A[start] <= A[final])
                ? A[start++] : A[final++];
        }
        else {
            compares++;
            mas[j] = (start <= middle)
                ? A[start++] : A[final++];
        }
    }

    for (j = first; j < last; j++) {
        swaps++;
        A[j] = mas[j];
    }
    delete[] mas;
};

void MergeSort(int* A, int first, int last) {
    if (first < last) {
        MergeSort(A, first, (first + last) / 2);
        MergeSort(A, (first + last) / 2 + 1, last);
        Merge(A, first, last);
    }
}

int main() {
    int i;
    int* A = new int[N];
    srand(time(NULL));
    for (i = 0; i < N; i++) {

        A[i] = rand();
    }
    cout << endl;
    double T, t1, t0;
    t0 = Th();
    MergeSort(A, 0, N);
    t1 = Th();
    T = (t1 - t0) / 1000.0;
    cout << "Merge sort" << endl;
    cout << "Number of elements:" << N << endl;
    cout << "compares=" << compares << endl;
    cout << "swaps=" << swaps << endl;
    cout << "Time:" << T << endl;
    delete[] A;
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: а где цифры, версии компиляторов (хотя подозреваю, тут просто студийный компилятор

Comment: visual studio..

Comment: осталось выяснить цифры - сколько выполнялся каждый вариант

Comment: я сделал для 800,8000,80000 элементов всегда быстрая сортировка было быстрее

Comment: 1) Ну так быстрая сортировка неспроста называется "быстрой" :) Почему вы решили, что на случайных данных она должна работать медленнее сортировки слиянием? 2) В сортировке слиянием в рекурсивной функции вы динамически выделяете/освобождаете память. Это не бесплатное удовольствие.

Comment: Вашу реализацию слияния можно ускорить, но в среднем, quicksort все равно будет быстрее.